# Updating time for key in couchbase

Tags: python, concurrency, couchbase

I have the system which sends concurrent **get** queries to couchbase. Every time the system gets **existing** key, it should update(prolongate) its lifetime. The amount of time is not so important and measures by days: the main idea is that key should be removed after nobody gets it for some time (20 days for example).

I guess that `touch` operation should be used, but should I `lock` keys, which would make things more difficult? Is it ok to use memcached package (it seems does not have `lock` API, but perhaps `gets` should do the trick)?

```py
import pylibmc


class Cache(Singleton):

    def init(self):
        self.mc = pylibmc.Client(
            # connection settings here
        )

    def get(self, key):
        """get key without locking it and update lifetime"""
        result = self.mc.get(key)
        if result:
            # prolongate key for another 20 days
            self.mc.touch(key, 60*60*24*20)

        return result

     def get_and_lock(self, key):
         """lock the key while getting it and update lifetime"""
         # should use couchbase package as memcached does not have lock API
         # or use 'gets' instead?
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that you mixed up two independent topics.

First is the `touch` operation with the new lifetime as a param. This sets the new time to live for the data object respectively.

The lock operation is unrelated to the time to live. Naturally, [Couchbase uses optimistic locking](https://developer.couchbase.com/documentation/server/4.0/sdks/dotnet-2.2/durability.html) (by utilizing a CAS value) to guarantee the consistency of updates. This means that the data object is not locked because locking is expensive and very often useless (because there is no other operation requesting the locked object in the meantime) but there is CAS value which is changed by every update. Nevertheless if you know beforehand that the data object will be accessed very often (which means there will be a lot of concurring updates) you can decide to use a pessimistic locking (i.e. the lock operation). But this behaviour is not related to the time to live at all (by the way it is possible to give a time to live to locks, too).

Conclusion: Your `touch` command would work. Never use pessimistic locking if you don't know that you really need it. Optimistic locking is perfect for most cases (there is a reason why Couchbase chose the optimistic locking as default behaviour!)

Better solution for your implementation: According to the [API](http://docs.couchbase.com/sdk-api/couchbase-python-client-2.0.0-beta/_modules/couchbase/bucket.html#Bucket.get) you can give the get operation a ttl param as well. Like

```
get(key, ttl=60*60*24*20)
```

This will modify the ttl of the object you got and you won't need the additional `touch` command!